# C# Conflict Error - The type X exists in both

Tags: c#, devexpress

i'm trying to inherits splashScreen 
like this

```
public partial class frmSplashScreen : SplashScreen
{
```

and i do the import `using DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen;`
and i got error

> The type 'DevExpress.XtraSplashScreen.SplashScreen' exists in both
>   'c:\Program Files\DevExpress
>   2011.2\Components\Bin\Framework\DevExpress.XtraEditors.v11.2.dll' and 'c:\Program Files\DevExpress\DXperience
>   12.2\Bin\Framework\DevExpress.XtraEditors.v12.2.dll'

i have two versions of devexpress so is there a problem to use both at the same time ?

Comment: You are referencing two versions of devexpress, remove from references older version. It's a problem cause compiler can't decide which one to use.

Comment: thanks it works when i removed old versions from the reference folder .

Answer (score 1):

- **Remove** the project's **Bin** and **Obj** folders;
- **Clean** and **Rebuild** the project.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. You can't use both.

Since the `Devexpress` assemblies preserve their namespaces / class names along different versions, you'll get ambiguity in this case.

You need to *un*-reference one of them.